# TexStudio: Could not start Default Compiler:Default Compiler: "/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex"

Tags: texstudio, mactex

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!
I did research on google trying to fix this error but no luck so far.

Machine: **macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7**

MacTex: **2021 newest version**

TexStudio **3.1.1(git3.1.1) Using Qt Version 5.15.2**

**/Library/Tex** contains the following symbolic links:

> drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   256  6 Apr 15:16 Distributions/

> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    38  6 Apr 15:16 Documentation@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Doc

> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    45  6 Apr 15:16 Local@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/TexmfLocal

> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    39  6 Apr 15:16 Root@ -> Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Root

> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    29  6 Apr 15:16 texbin@ -> Distributions/Programs/texbin

**/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/** contains the following:

> lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel                    6  6 Apr 15:14 pdflatex@ -> pdftex

> lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel                    6  6 Apr 15:14 pdfmex@ -> pdftex

TeXstudio -> Help -> Check LaTeX Installation shows

> Default Compiler (compile) (r): "/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Setting "default compiler" back to default value (txs:///pdflatex) gives the following error:

[image]

**help/check latex installation**

dpi: 72
which pdflatex: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex

PDFLATEX: "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)

Environment variables:
HOME=/Users/me
LOGNAME=me
PATH=/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2020:/usr/local/texlive/2021:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin
SHELL=/bin/bash

TeXstudio:
Path : /Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio
Program call: /Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio
Setting file: /Users/me/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini

Command configuration in TeXstudio:

PdfLaTeX (pdflatex) (r): "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
LaTeX (latex) (r): "/Library/TeX/texbin/latex" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
Additional Search Paths:
Command: /usr/local/texlive/2020:/usr/local/texlive/2021:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin
Log:
Pdf:

**terminal pdflatex**
$ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
**
Please type the name of your input file.
**test.tex
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test.tex'.
<*> test.tex

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)

Comment: Try `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` instead.

Comment: Thanks @HerbSchulz. Yes I tried /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex as well but it did not work either.

Comment: In Terminal what do `which pdflatex` and `echo $PATH` return? Do you have multiple TeX Distributions?

Comment: Thanks Herb. These are the outputs but i don't know how to format them to look nice. 

$ which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
 
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: If you installed MacTeX try using TeXShop just to see if it’s TeXStudio or something involving your distribution.

Comment: Wait.... try to set the default compiler to just pdflatex. TeXStudio may take that as using the pdflatexyou defined already.

Comment: Setting "default compiler" back to default value (txs:///pdflatex) gives a new error, updated  in the questions above. Also, I tried Texshop which comes by default with Mactex and it works with no problem.